# how to hide border from react-html5video

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, html5-video

I render video player from react-html5video library and can't remove black border.[image]

Here is the code snippet:

```
<Video
                      ref={videoRef}
                      playsInline
                      autoPlay={true}
                      muted={false}
                      loop={false}
          
                    >
                      <source
                        defer
                        src={i.url}
                        type="video/MP4"
                        className="video"
                      />
css styling for .video :

.video {
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: auto;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}
```

Comment: How about `border: none !important`?

Comment: Try to change `overflow-x: auto` to `overflow-x: hidden` to see if this border isn't a part of the horizontal scroll.